# Whats wrong with my arduino code?

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm a complete noob at the arduino code, so this may seem stupid, but, why is my code not working?

```
    // IRremote - Version: Latest 
    #include <IRremote.h>
    #include <IRremoteInt.h>
    int ledPin = 9; 

    /*

    */

    void setup() 
    {
      analogWrite(9,0);
      Serial.begin(9600);
      irrecv.enableIRIn();

    void loop(); 
    {
       if (irrecv.decode(4294967295));
        {
          analogWrite(9,255);
          analogWrite(9,0);
          delay(500]);
            irrecv.resume();   
            if (irrecv.decode(4294967295));
             {
               analogWrite(9,0);
             }
        }
    }
```

Also, on line 14, it says "'irrecv was not declared on this scope."

Comment: FYI: I'm mostly just cobbling together segments of other code.

Comment: Semicolons are not something you can just randomly sprinkle throughout your code - one is required at the end of each statement.  Square brackets and curly braces are not something you can just randomly sprinkle throughout your code - they always come in pairs.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I noticed:

You have to set your pin mode for your output:

```
void setup(){
   //SET YOUR PINMODE HERE
   pinmode(9,OUTPUT)
   //THEN SET IT TO LOW / 0
   analogWrite(9,0)
}
```

I can't say anything about your IRr library but your if statement has a possible error also. You need to set the pin high (light on) then wait for 500 ms and then shut it. You are blinking it so fast you cannot see the light.

```
void loop() {
       if (irrecv.decode(4294967295)) 
        {
          analogWrite(9,255)
          delay(500)     <--- HERE is the right place for the delay
          analogWrite(9,0)
          //delay(500])  <--- NOT HERE and remove "]" -bracket
        }
```

I hope this helps a bit at least. Remember: Always set your inputs and outputs in the setup function.

Take a look at the link below. There you can see how are the pins set and so on. 
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogWrite

Comment: it still sees the 'irrecv.enableIRIn()' as an error. "'irrecv' was not declared on this scope."                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                  
        delay(1000) // <--- HERE is the right place for the delay

        ^

        exit status 1

Comment: Is the edited code section in your question as it is? You dont have a closing bracket in the setup void!